# Using PANDAS to conditionally manipulate specific cells based on another cell

Tags: python, pandas

```
'''if andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['Datacenter'] == 'ACT1']:
andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['payout']] * .25
   elif andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['Datacenter'] == 'ATL2']:
andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['payout']] * .25
   else:
andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['payout']] * 1
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'''
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to manipulate the 'payout' column based on the corresponding "Datacenter" cell within the row.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `numpy.where` and `numpy.select`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of if-else:

`andrew_ramirez[andrew_ramirez['Datacenter'].isin(['ATL2','ACT1'])]['payout']*= 0.25`

The code `andrew_ramirez['Datacenter'].isin(['ATL2','ACT1'])` returns a True for rows of the Datacenter of the following categories(ATL2 and ACT1)
Giving it as a dateframe it returns all the rows with the category required and all the columns.
Now, using 'payout' we return the rows of the required category of the payout column. Then we use the *= to update the values.